# How much the load can jmeter take with a single JSON Request?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

I am using:- 
 - windows10,
 - processor: Intel Core i3@2.00GHz,
 - RAM:8.00GB,
 - 64- bit OS.
 - jmeter 4.0

the scenario is I have to pass/send a request for JSON data in Jmeter body.
I have to pass/send request of 50mb JSON data in the JMeter body.

But the problem is when my JSON data size more than 700kb, after that my system has freeze/not responding.

So, how can I pass/send request of JSON data size from 700kb to 50mb in JMeter with a single Request?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
2. Make sure to increase JVM Heap Size so your file will fit into memory given the number of threads you're going to use multiplied by file size plus ~1 GB for JMeter to operate.
3. Follow recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure), especially:

   - don't use any Listeners
   - don't save request/response data
4. You can also consider using [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) plugin which is capable of [sending files to the server without loading it into memory first](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/fileupload-test-with-JMeter-td4267154.html).